# White space between td in table in gmail

Tags: css, gmail, html-table, whitespace

I have a table and I send it as html on gmail but there are white gaps in it. It's due to gmail, I suppose. There is white space between two td.
How to remove it?

My code is:

```html
 <table>         
            <tr class="empty"><td></td></tr>
            <tr class="empty"><td></td></tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="4" style="background-color: #007C66 !important; color:white !important;">
                    Company:
                </td>
                <td colspan="4" style="background-color: #007C66 !important; color:white !important;">
                    Employee:
                </td>
            </tr>
   //other code
   </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is default cell spacing in tables. Set `cellspacing="0"` in table.

```
<table cellspacing="0">         
        <tr class="empty"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="empty"><td></td></tr>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" style="background-color: #007C66 !important; color:white !important;">
                Company:
            </td>
            <td colspan="4" style="background-color: #007C66 !important; color:white !important;">
                Employee:
            </td>
        </tr>//other code
</table>
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e08yk0x5/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll use it! :)